# Saving _joinData not working well

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

I'm having trouble editing associated data of an extra field of a join table. I have this:

```
        $brigada = $this->Brigadas
        ->findById($id)
        ->contain(['Tags', 'Voluntarios']) // load associated Voluntarios
        ->firstOrFail();
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {


        $this->Brigadas->patchEntity($brigada, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Voluntarios._joinData']]);
        if ($this->Brigadas->save($brigada)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your team data has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your team data.'));
    }
```

My issue is this: I am able to load the associated voluntarios for each brigada through a table called Participaciones, which is basically a join table with an extra field called *liders* which determines whether a voluntario is a team leader for that team. Everything works well as in loading a boolean field.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($brigada->voluntarios); ++$i):
    $voluntario = $brigada->voluntarios[$i];
    echo $this->Form->control(
        'voluntarios.' . $i . '._joinData.lider',
            [
                'label' => $voluntario->full_name,
            ]
        );
        endfor ?>
```

Which works perfectly. My problem comes when I save, since it doesn't record anything. I've worked on this for days to no avail, and my only clue to why it doesn't work is this: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6100. If I add the recommended piece of code `$this->request->data['voluntarios'] = array_values($this->request->data['voluntarios']);`, it saves! But in exchange, it basically turns all of my associated data into null. My (very) limited programming experience makes me believe that there is a discrepancy between the way that the _joinData is setup and I need to transform it individually perhaps in order to save, but I have gotten to a dead end and I have nowhere to turn. Can someone please help me put an end to my suffering? :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the end was to adapt the solution I put above, which was to setup everything manually in the controller. Something in the form of:

```
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924459/cakephp-3-belongstomany-with-joindata
    $this->request->data['voluntarios'] = [
        ['id' => '1', '_joinData' => ['lider' => '0']],

    ];
```

Into a painfully nested answer. Why the need to make this manually beats me, but at least it works. I hope someone finds this useful.

```
                if (!empty($this->request->data['voluntarios']['_ids'])) {
                $vol = [];
                foreach ($this->request->data['voluntarios']['_ids'] as $key=>$locationId) {
                    $lider = $this->Brigadas->Participaciones->find()
                        ->select(['voluntario_id','lider'])
                        ->hydrate(false)
                        ->where(['voluntario_id' => $locationId, 'brigada_id' => $id])
                        ->first();
                    $vol[] = [
                        'id' => (string)($key+1),
                        '_joinData' => [
                            'lider' => isset($this->request->data['voluntarios'][$key]['_joinData']['lider']) ? $this->request->data['voluntarios'][$key]['_joinData']['lider'] : false
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }

    $this->Brigadas->patchEntity($brigada, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Brigadas->save($brigada)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your team data has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $id]);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your team data.'));
    }
```